# Java HashMap How to get the set of keys that is not linked to the HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a HashMap that stores data that need to be changed. I need to figure out how many fields are in the HashMap, not counting "comments" and "debug". My solution was to simply get the keySet, and remove the columns I don't want to count, like this:

```
// Create and populate the HashMap
HashMap<String, String> updates = new HashMap<>();
makeUpdates(updates);
if (somecondition) {
    updates.put("comments", commentUpdater("Some Comment"));
}
updates.put("debug", getDebugInfo());

// Get the updated keys
Set<String> updatedFields = updates
updatedFields.remove("comments");
updatedFields.remove("debug");
System.out.println("The following " + updatedFields.size() + 
    " fields were updated: " + updatedFields.toString());
```

The problem, of course, is that removing "comments" and "debug" from the set also removes them from the HashMap. How can I break this link, or get a copy of the set that is not linked to the HashMap?

Comment: Why not just subtract two from the total and filter it on output?

Comment: Not shown in the code (editing to fix), is the edge case where sometimes, the comments field is not actually set.

Comment: I’m not convinced “comments” and “debug” should be in the map at all. If these keys are to be treated differently, it may be preferable to keep them separate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a copy

```
Set<String> updatedFields = new HashSet<>(updates.keySet());
```

Now, you can remove strings from `updatedFields` which won't affect the `updates` map.

Or as @Elliott Frisch mentioned, you can filter it

```
Set<String> updatedFields = updates.keySet()
                                   .stream()
                                   .filter(key -> !"comments".equals(key) && !"debug".equals(key))
                                   .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new `HashSet` and initialize it with the elements of the `HashMap`'s `keySet()`:

```
Set<String> updatedFields = new HashSet<>(updates.keySet());
```